# Determinants question with factorials

Tags: determinant, factorial

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
     n! & (n+1)! & (n+2)!\\
     (n+1)! & (n+2)! & (n+3)! \\
     (n+2)! & (n+3)! & (n+4)!
     \end{pmatrix}$$

And $D=\det(A)$,
We have to prove that $D/(n!)^3 - 4$ is divisible by $n$.

I did it by simplifying the determinant using some row and column operations and finally ended up in getting a cubic polynomial in $n$. Then I subtracted 4 from the polynomial and got the result.

Is there any other way I could prove the result quicker and in a better manner?

Comment: I doubt it. Determinants are notoriously difficult.

Comment: I have, like you, factorized three times (n!) in each column and computed the simplified determinant as the third degree polynomials $4+10n+8n^2+2n^3$. I am almost certain that no simpler method exist.

Comment: @JeanMarie See my answer for a simpler treatment.

Comment: @Erick Wong I didn't thought about that. Thanks !

Comment: @setholopolus Determinants are, historically, extremely well-studied objects (Lewis Carroll even has a theorem on determinants).  I'm really not sure what you mean by notoriously difficult: certainly there are a lot of tools available for working with them, much more so than, say, permanents.

Answer (score 22):

$$
\begin{align}
D&=\det\begin{bmatrix}
n!&(n+1)!&(n+2)!\\
(n+1)!&(n+2)!&(n+3)!\\
(n+2)!&(n+3)!&(n+4)!
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=n!(n+1)!(n+2)!
\det\small\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
n+1&n+2&n+3\\
(n+1)(n+2)&(n+2)(n+3)&(n+3)(n+4)\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}\\
&=n!(n+1)!(n+2)!
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&2\\
0&2n+4&4n+10\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}\\
&=n!(n+1)!(n+2)!
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
0&1&2\\
0&0&2\\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}\\[12pt]
&=2n!(n+1)!(n+2)!\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: divide columns by $n!$, $(n+1)!$, $(n+2)!$ respectively
$(2)$: subtract $n+1$ times row $1$ from row $2$
$\phantom{\text{(2):}}$ subtract $(n+1)(n+2)$ times row $1$ from row $3$
$(3)$: subtract $2n+4$ times row $2$ from row $3$
$(4)$: evaluate the determinant

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{D}{n!^3}-4
&=2(n+1)^2(n+2)-4\\[6pt]
&=n\left(2n^2+8n+10\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very neat answer! (+1)

Answer (score 15):

Following hypergeometric's answer, we have an exact expression for $D/(n!)^3$.  All that remains is to show $D/(n!)^3 \equiv 4 \pmod{n}$.  Since we just want the determinant of $B$ mod $n$ we can reduce the matrix entries mod $n$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&2\\
1&2&6\\
2&6&24
\end{bmatrix},$$

and a routine calculation gives a determinant $4$.

Comment: $ \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&2\\ 1&2&6\\ 2&6&24 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&2\\ 0&1&4\\ 0&4&20 \end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&2\\ 0&1&4\\ 0&0&4 \end{bmatrix}$ (+1)

Comment: Very nice! (+1)

Comment: @Eric Wong, Could you please elaborate your answer? I couldn't understand the meaning of mod n and the rest.

Comment: @PreethamKrishna The "mod $n$" refers to modular arithmetic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  The determinant of a matrix is a polynomial function of its entries, so its value modulo $n$ can be computed using only the residues of the entries modulo $n$.

Comment: @Eric Wong: What do you mean by residues of the entries and how did you get the matrix that you have written in your answer? Actually your method sounds very new to me that's why I'm having doubts

Comment: @PreethamKrishna You have to read the background material I linked to before you can make sense of it.

Answer (score 4):

Factorizing the matrix might help a bit.

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
     n! & (n+1)! & (n+2)!\\
     (n+1)! & (n+2)! & (n+3)! \\
     (n+2)! & (n+3)! & (n+4)!
     \end{pmatrix}=n!\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & (n+1) &(n+1)^{\overline{2}}\\
     (n+1) & (n+1)^{\overline{2}} & (n+1)^{\overline{3}} \\
     \;\;(n+1)^{\overline{2}} & (n+1)^{\overline{3}} & (n+1)^{\overline{4}}
     \end{pmatrix}}_B$$
using the [Pochhammer notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) for a rising factorial.

$D/(n!)^3$ is then just the determinant of $B$.

Comment: You can then factor out $(n+1)$ off the $2^{nd}$ column and $(n+1)(n+2)$ off the $3^{rd}$.

Comment: I hope you don't mind; I changed the falling factorials to rising factorials.

Comment: @robjohn - Yes, that's correct. Thanks!

Comment: @dxiv - Thanks for the helptul tip. Won't edit further since robjohn has already posted a very nice answer along the same lines.